# push_back whole array wchar_t[n] to vector<wchar_t> efficiently

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Why I use `vector<wchar_t>` instead of `vector<array<wchar_t, n> >`, if you are interested:

> I want to store a lot of wchar_t arrays with different sizes together
>   so that I can write it all to a file later after some encrypt/compress process.
>
> I don't know how many arrays are there before I start, so I chose to use `vector`.
>
> But these arrays are not the same size and I want them to be stored next to each
>   other, so I can't use something like `vector<array<wchar_t, n> >`.

---

The only way I can think of doing this is push_back every wchar_t in every array one by one, and I think it is not efficient, because copy a string by yourself is always slower than `strcpy`, and every time I `push_back` it will check about capacity which is unnecessary in this case.

Is there any better solution?

I was hoping something like `push_back(array_address, n)`.

Comment: Why not use vector<vector<wchar_t>> ?

Comment: @biseibutsu see comment in Mojave's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you need a vector of vectors of wchar_ts, but with the condition that vectors of wchar_ts are stored contiguously in base vector. Something like:

```
vector<vector<wchar_t>> v = {"string""value""list"};
```

The question is you need this for performance (means that that you can access each string separately, but they are in same space) or just need a contiguous array of strings to process it later?

If is the first then you need to make your own container that have these properties, if is the second then just append sequences to the vector, but if you want to use the memxxx functions then you may try this:

```
v.resize(v.size() + arr_sz);
std::copy_n(std::begin(sz), arr_sz, v.end() - arr_sz);
```

that is because (at least in VC++ 2013) copy_n uses memxxx on scalar types values:

```
template<class _InIt,
    class _Diff,
    class _OutIt> inline
    _OutIt _Copy_n(_InIt _First, _Diff _Count,
        _OutIt _Dest, _Scalar_ptr_iterator_tag)
    {   // copy [_First, _First + _Count) to [_Dest, ...), pointers to scalars
    _CSTD memmove(&*_Dest, &*_First,
        _Count * sizeof (*_First));
    return (_Dest + _Count);
    }
```

Comment: If I use vector<vector<wchar_t>>, will the strings be stored in memory contiguously? I don't need to access each string.

Comment: @JasonX No, they will not, because each vector have is own handle (items buffer) in different memory locations (though allocators tend to put them as close as possible, it is not guaranteed). If you just need a contiguous array of wchar_t then just append your strings with insert or copy_n to vector. Also if you have a lot of strings your vector will reallocate few times, for efficiency will be good to preallocate vector to some value close to maximum sum of strings lengths or at least (maybe to have a special variable that counts lengths).

Answer (score 0):

Considering a container `src`, and your vector of `wchar_t`use the insert method :

```
std::vector<wchar_t> dst;
dst.insert( end(dst), begin(src), end(src));
```

But there is no strong guarantee that it will optimize to a plain memcpy in case of a POD type or even a native type.